# Create Jetty Connectors in Pax-Web

Tags: jetty, apache-karaf, karaf, pax, pax-web

Is there a possibility (API) to add Jetty connectors via Pax-Web programmatically. Pax-Web internally uses a nice `JettyServer` interface, but there seems to be no OSGi service available. The ports that must be available are not known in advance, so I cannot use `jetty.xml` for configuration purposes.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

As you just seem to want to change the port you should do it the OSGi way and just configure pax web with the appropriate configuration. See also here: https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Basic+Configuration

The configuration in question is 
org.osgi.service.http.port

This port can be configured by the config admin service. In case of a configuration change the jetty server will be restarted.

Regarding the initial question about a service, this is not possible right now but there is a JIRA issue for it available, and contributions are highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that I require several ports (more than one) and I want to bind each of the providers to a specific port. The attribute `org.osgi.service.http.port` allows only one port. That is not enough.

Comment: In that case yes, this could be a nice enhancement. Contributions welcome. :-)

Comment: Ok, the next version 4.1. will have something for this, see https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXWEB-768

Comment: That sounds really good... A pretty nice solution would be to create a solution also using OSGi Declarative Services. We can use the capabilities of the Configuration Admin and bind a connector instance to its configuration (ManagedServiceFactory). I made that several times and it would provide you a very flexible solution that allows creation and (re-)configuration of connector instances from the outside.

Comment: I have implemented a hand-made solution based on the Equinox HTTP Service. It works, but now things must run within Apache Karaf and my solution does not complete fit in this environment. It is working, but it would be nice to rely on an official implementation. Maybe in future via Pax Web 4.1 and Apache Karaf 4.0 ;-)

Comment: Well, since it is a OSGi service feel free to use declarative services with it. Beware that with every new connector or handler the server will restart.

Comment: Btw. PAXWEB-768 is resolved and version 4.1 is released. So it's possible to configure connectors/handlers via services.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from PaxWeb 4.1.0 you can register the connectors you need by registering them as service (it allows for instance to exclude the SSL protocols against Poodle vulnerability)

```
    SslContextFactory contextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    contextFactory.addExcludeProtocols("SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3");
    contextFactory.setKeyStorePath("PATH_TO_KEYSTORE");
    contextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD");
    contextFactory.setTrustStore("PATH_TO_TRUSTSTORE");
    contextFactory.setTrustStorePassword("TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD");
    contextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true);
    contextFactory.setWantClientAuth(true);

    Connector sc = new SslSelectChannelConnector(contextFactory);
    sc.setPort(8443);
    ServiceRegistration<Connector> registerService = bundleContext.registerService(Connector.class, sc, null);
```

Mainly taken from pax web documentation http://ops4j.github.io/pax/web/SNAPSHOT/

Comment: I am using Jetty 9.2.x and the classes `SelectChannelConnector` or  `SslSelectChannelConnector` are no longer available. There is now the class `ServerConnector` that requires the `Server` for instantiation which is not exposed by PaxWeb.